# Adding a numbered list through an output for a loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm looking to add a numbered list through an output I have of mine. I then want to be able to assign that numbered list as a variable, so that I can send it to my database later on.

I want the numbered list to reflect the output.

For example, if there were 10 names outputted, I want the first name to be given number 1, and so fourth. Then when the number is sent to my db, I want that number to be affiliated with that person.

How can I do this?

Expected results:

```
<div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div> 
 <form method="post">
<?php
    foreach ($array as $result) :
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']); 
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php //echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you wanted. I'm assuming it's a counter?

```
Results: <br>   
<div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div> 
 <form method="post">
<?php
$count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $result) :
        $count++;
        $shuffle_count = $count;
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_count; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php //echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">

<?php 

    endforeach;
```

Feel free to point out if I've misunderstood you...

Comment: The numbers aren't being echoed out.

Comment: And when I configure it to send to my database, every person has the number 4. So it is counting the users rather than labeling them as 1, 2, 3, 4